# How to understand server/client data transfer in Angular, when coming from JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jsp

I have a good basic knowledge of how to create web applications using java and jsp, together with Expression Language and JSTL. I am trying to learn how to use Angular.js for my front end.

I've gone through several tutorials, and I am starting to get a fair grip of the basics. But I have yet to figure out how to transfer data from the server, to the front end. Most tutorials I've found, describe how to send data from the front end, to the server.

I know that a RESTful api back end is recommended for Angular web apps. Unfortunately, I have no experience with this, and I find it hard to learn both angular and RESTful at the same time. If possible, I would love to make a work around, so that I can use my existing server solution, and learn one element at the time.

**Server side setup**

Now, in my old setup, using `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`, i call the `service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`-method. Inside the method, i add attributes to the request, like this:

```
request.setAttribute("attribute1", "1");
request.setAttribute("attribute2", "2");
request.setAttribute("attribute3", "3");
```

Then, because of a front controller pattern, I pass these request variables on to a redirect like this:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/" + myPageVar + ".jsp").
forward(request, response);
```

For now, I would ideally like to keep this server side setup.

**Current client side data access:**

In the current setup, I can now access the initiated variables in two different ways. Either in a javascript script, like below (does not work with objects, only simpler attributes like strings (including JSON)). the next lines of code is picked from a jsp-page that the servlet would have redirected to.

```
var attribute1 = ${requestScope.attribute1};
```

or in the html, like this (would work with objects):

```
<c:set var="attribute1" value="${requestScope.attribute1}"></c:set>
```

I guess that I could incorporate Expression Language, and use javascript variables to initialize variables in my angular modules, directives and controllers, but I would prefer to do it purely in Angular.

Are these attributes accessible in any way, using angular? I've been trying to read up on $http, and $scope, but there is a jungle of non-relevant info on those, which I haven't been able to navigate through yet.

Comment: i think you should study JAX-RS, and do it using RestFul.

Comment: I might have to :). Thanks for the input. I'll wait a little while, to see if anyone has a work adround that allows me to learn one element at the time though.

Comment: Are you using spring?

Comment: No. I started out by implementing a front controller pattern from scratch, to learn as much as possible about the basics.

Comment: Spring MVC could provide an easy and fast solution for RESTful services, I could answer with an example that returns and recieves json which angular manipulates easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data you want to make accessible to angular should be ready when user lands on the page, it could make sense to put data in javascript variable in jsp page as you suggest. 
Since your var is in global scope you can get in your angular controller like this:

```
$scope.att1 = attribute1;
```

However if you want to update your data without re-rendering the whole page (and that is what you want pretty soon) you should use $http to call a servlet that returns json. You can relatively simply make this servlet without jax-rs by overriding doGet in httpServlet and use a lightweight json lib (like gson). This example will do it:

```
//Set up pojo and make it into json string:
SomeClass pojo =new SomeClass();
pojo.setX("this is X");
JSONObject jsonObject = new Gson().toJson(pojo);
String jsonStr=jsonObject.toJSONString();
//Modify response and write json string
httpServletResponse.setStatus(200);//We are ok
httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/json");
httpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
Writer writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
writer.write(jsonStr);
writer.close();
//Thats it
```

In a simple setup you handle this response in your controller like this:

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://yourservleturl' })
.success(function(jsonStringFromServlet){
  $scope.newData = jsonStringFromServlet;
})
.error(function(){
  $scope.error = true;
});
```

In page-html you access the data with

```
<div>This is your new x: {{newData.x}}</div>
```

Comment: this still relies on jsps, and uses a plain old servlet instead of one of the multitude of frameworks

Comment: @NimChimpsky 1) The question is about using jsp and without any rest framework 2) This is a perfectly valid requirement since angularjs is all about thick clients and lightweight serverside.

Comment: I really like this answer, and to sum it up: 1) Retrieving data from the request scope, is out of scope for angular, but can be achieved by using my current Expression Language. 2) The other option would be to implement functions that write JSON to the response, which seems similar, yet not equal to the way I do ajax calls now. I am familiar with Gson.

Summary: I can keep my server side, as long as I keep my Expression Language to retrieve the variables, but it will be a bit hacky. By the way @JacobNicolaisen, I think you might be working in the building right next to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use jsps at all, don't set attributes.

Only use static html, thats the benefit ! You can write angular directives that perform the funcationality of jsp includes, and have much cleaner code (no embedded jstl, java. just pure html).

Create server side code that returns json. Then your angular js code calls the rest api and populates the client side model.

If you have something that needs populating on startup, use javascript appropriately.

Here is a typical java method that returns json, using Jersey (similar to Spring MVC, resteasy, restlets, spark, apache cxf etc etc) :

```
    @PATH("/myPojo")
    @GET
    public Response getPojo(Long id) {
        Pojo pojo = myService.getPojo(id)
        return Response.ok()
                       .entity(pojo)
                       .build();
    }
```

In angualr you can then create, for example, `$myPojoService.getPojo()` that is injected to relevant controllers and calls this endpoint. When called it probably returns the pojo as json and then probably populates the `$scope.model.pojo` json object. Then the two way databinding of angular updates your gui ... and Boom, you are a full stack engineer/ front end dev!

Comment: Original question specifies "I know that a RESTful api back end is recommended for Angular web apps...If possible, I would love to make a work around, so that I can use my existing server solution, "

Comment: @NicholasSmith doesn;t mean its the best way

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to accomplish this.  This is just what I ended up using.

To expose values in your JSP to Angular you'll need to write them out in script tags and build up Javascript vars with them.  Then you can access them from Angular.  I'm doing this to pass-in authenticated user account information from server side to my angular code.  Your JSP would contain code such as:

```
<script>
  window.CURRENT_USER = {
    id: <%=currentUser.getId()%>,
    name: "<%=currentUser.getName()%>",
    email: "<%=currentUser.getEmail()%>",
    prevLogin: new Date(<%=currentUser.getPrevLoginAt().getTime()%>),
    prevLoginIp: "<%=currentUser.getPrevLoginIp()%>"    
  };
</script>
```

Then in your angular controllers, you can access it like this:

```
var currentUser = $window.CURRENT_USER;
```

A better approach (mentioned by **Jacob Nicolaisen**) would be to use the Google GSon library to actually generate the JSON objects instead of hand coding them.)

Comment: this still relies on JSP's, which is a negative

Comment: @NimChimpsky The question specifies that he wants to do this using his existing setup, he doesn't want to use REST services or make API calls.  Even Google AdWords team uses this approach to cut down on number of initial API calls by embedding initial values into the page server-side.

Comment: good for them, I think getting rid of jsp is one of the main benefits of angular If you want to use jsps don;t bother with angular - you end up with a halfway house that is not particualrly good.

Comment: Here's the ng-conf video discussing it. Talks about why they moved to server-side rendering of some content to improve experience / performance https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg&feature=player_detailpage#t=157

Comment: thats a specific corner case for user authrization in which the devs decied to use jsp for this parctiular use case and app... as a general rule, get rid of them

Comment: Is it JSPs specifically you'd get rid of, or any server-side rendering?  Most serious large-scale javascript apps I've looked at do some pre-rendering of the page (or javascript data).  discourse.org developers have mentioned using it on their platform.  http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/10/why-discourse-uses-emberjs.html see point 2 under **Client Side MVC Performance**

Comment: "Discourse only requests JSON when you change views. " eh ?  How about you tell me why you like jsps ? You like the three different languages embedded within one another ? You like the fact that your designers/front end devs have to learn some java/jstl ? You like the fact that becuase its not static html you can't just simply cache it ? you think the syntax is great, myPojo.getVar becomes myPojo.var : super intuitive right ?

Comment: Guys, I love every input I get from this discussion. Your attempts to both give me a direct answer, and provide best practice alternatives, are combined giving me the best possible way to actually understanding angular's potential. I'll read through the answers more thouroughly, and accept the one that most directly answers my question though.

Comment: I have to say though, that this particular answer relies on scriptlets, which has not been recommended to use, since way before I learned JSP. The scriptlets would be replaced with Expression Language now, but as I wrote in the question: *I guess that I could incorporate Expression Language, and use javascript variables to initialize variables in my angular modules, directives and controllers, but I would prefer to do it purely in Angular.*